# C++ running on ubuntu touch?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

Is it possible to run code written in a language like C++, C, C# ect. on ubuntu touch?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to run it as though it was a normal Ubuntu distro, as long as you compile it first.

Steps for compiling on Ubuntu [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Compile-a-C/C%2B%2B-Program-on-Ubuntu-Linux).

You may be able to compile it in Windows or another OS as well with `g++ myprog.cpp -o myprog` <sub>*(where `myprog.cpp` is the written C program, and `myprog` is the compiled output)*</sub>, if the Ubuntu Touch distro does not allow it.